# Configure Windows RAID-5 "drive failed" timeout?

Tags: windows, raid, software-raid, raid5

### Background

When a hard-drive controller detects an error, and needs to remap a sector, the drive normally becomes unresponsive for the seconds (or possibly minutes) it takes to try to complete the re-mapping.

With the drive no longer responding, a host RAID controller can assume that the drive has failed, and mark it as unreliable.

Some hard-drive models, from some manufacturers, have a feature to limit (in seconds) how long the drive will spend trying to remap a sector. Different drive manufacturers give different names to this feature:

- [Time-Limited Error Recovery (**TLER**)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-Limited_Error_Recovery): *Western Digital*
- Error Recovery Control (**ERC**): *Seagate*
- [Command Completion Time Limit (CCTL)](http://blog.disksurvey.org/2012/07/17/disk-error-recovery/): *Samsung, Hitachi*

**Note**: The correct term from the ATA/ATAPI command set is *Command Completion Time Limit* ([CCTL](http://www.t13.org/Documents/UploadedDocuments/docs2008/D1699r6a-ATA8-ACS.pdf))

By limiting the time the drive spends trying to recover a sector, it ensures that the host RAID controller will not think that the drive has failed.

Different RAID controllers (hardware and software) have different *timeout* intervals. If the drive is unresponsive for longer than their *timeout* it will be marked as offline, e.g.:

- [3ware 9650SE: 20 s](http://kb.lsi.com/KnowledgebaseArticle15639.aspx)
- FreeBSD 6.3 (`kern.geom.mirror.timeout`): 4 s

### On to my question

> Is there an option in Windows that controls how long Windows will wait
>   before it decides a drive is not responding?

i do know of a registry setting called [`TimeoutValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

[**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Disk\TimeOutValue**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> - **TimeoutValue**
>
>   - Location: **HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Disk\TimeoutValue**
>   - Values: 1 - 255 seconds
>   - Meaning: Time in units of seconds before an SRB request initiated by the disk class driver will time out. If this registry value is not set, a default value of 10 seconds is used. Time-out values for requests that are initiated by class drivers vary according to the class driver.
>   - Operating system version: This feature is available in all versions of the Windows operating systems.

But this is only documented as applying to the **SCSI Miniport Driver**. And *even* if it also applies to my **SATA** drives, it doesn't guarantee that it also applies to Window's RAID-5 subsystem.

---

The reason i ask about adjusting the timeout in my (software) **controller** is because hard-drive manufacturers have started to get mean-spirited:

- no longer including the ability to limit the error-recovery time
- they intentionally lock one feature of the ATA/ATAPI command set behind a pay-wall.

For that firmware feature they want you to buy the more expensive ("*RAID Edition*") drives (e.g. 71% more expensive). Thus changing:

- [Rᴇᴅᴜɴᴅᴀɴᴛ Aʀʀᴀʏ ᴏꜰ Iɴᴇxᴘᴇɴsɪᴠᴇ Dɪsᴋs](http://digitalassets.lib.berkeley.edu/techreports/ucb/text/CSD-88-448.pdf)<sup>1</sup> (`RAID`), to
- Rᴇᴅᴜɴᴅᴀɴᴛ Aʀʀᴀʏ ᴏꜰ *Exᴘᴇɴsɪᴠᴇ* Dɪsᴋs

### Bonus Reading

- [Disks with TLER / ERC / CCTL & LCC [Table of drives]](http://hardforum.com/archive/index.php/t-1590200.html)

### See also

- [Green drives dropping from RAID, TLER/ERC problems?](http://forums.beyond.ca/showthread.php?threadid=328637)
- MSDN: [Registry Entries for SCSI Miniport Drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- StorageReview.com:[How to use "desktop" drives in RAID without TLER/ERC/CCTL](http://forums.storagereview.com/index.php/topic/29208-how-to-use-desktop-drives-in-raid-without-tlererccctl/)
- StorageReview.com:[TLER / CCTL Disks which can have their TLER / CCTL values changed](http://forums.storagereview.com/index.php/topic/28333-tler-cctl/)
- [LSI 15639, User Guide for 9650SE 9690SA from 9.5.2 Complete Codeset](http://kb.lsi.com/KnowledgebaseArticle15639.aspx)
- [T13 AT Attachment 8 - ATA/ATAPI Command Set (ATA8-ACS) (pdf)](http://www.t13.org/Documents/UploadedDocuments/docs2008/D1699r6a-ATA8-ACS.pdf)
- [Western Digital - Difference between Desktop edition and RAID (Enterprise) edition drives](http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1397/~/difference-between-desktop-edition-and-raid-(enterprise)-edition-drives)

<sup>1</sup> Yes, *inexpensive*. **Source**: ["A Case for Redundant Arrays of Inexpensive Disks (RAID)"](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~garth/RAIDpaper/Patterson88.pdf), D.A. Patterson, G. Gibson, and R.H. Katz, *ACM SIGMOD Conference*, June 1988, Chicago IL.

Comment: Just a nit picky note... RAID has not referred to inexpsensive disks for a while now... but rather independant disks. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID.  Also, to clarify are you using the built-in Windows (software controller) RAID functions as opposed to a hardware card?

Comment: @BrentPabst Yes.

Answer (score -2):

This doesn't really answer your question per se, but as a recommendation software RAID controllers, in my experience, are far less reliable than hardware controllers.  If you have the budget for them always opt for a stand-alone card to take the burden of disk IO off of the computer itself.

Comment: i'm concerned that if the card itself fails, the entire array is lost. i presume a RAID controller card from one manufacturer is incompatible with a raid controller card from another manufacturer, is incompatible with Microsoft's software solution. At least with a Windows software solution i am guaranteed future compatibility. And when it comes to data safety, confusion and fear is not something i want to have to deal with.

Comment: True... but if anything happens to your Windows installation your data could be lost as well.  You can also find redundant controllers or better yet just get a stand-alone DASD to connect to your server, it will have by far the best redundancy compared to either solution.  All a matter of how much money you want to throw at it versus how much money you can lose if it goes down.

Comment: Problem with a separate device is that if *it* dies then i lose all data. At least now i don't lose data.

Comment: True, but the same could be said of your Windows installation. You still have a single point of failure any way you look at it. At least the mean-downtime of a physical storage device is much higher than a server (ent. devices of course)

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by my "Windows installation" is a point of failure. If my Windows installation fails i can put in a Windows Server DVD, and 37 minutes later i have access to my data again. If my [Promise FastTrack 66](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/fast-inexpensive,175.html) card dies i (probably) lose my data.